# IFFT function in R?

Tags: r

In Matlab, there is an `ifft` function (Inverse fast Fourier transform) - [details](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html).

In particular, the following:

```
ifft(X,n,dim)
```

Which returns the inverse DFT of `X` across the dimension `dim`.

In R, there is a similar function apart of the `signal` package - [details](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/signal/html/ifft.html)

However it only allows for the x input array, as follows:

```
ifft(x)
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to include the extra dimension, such as dim in the Matlab function, with R?

Thank you so much for taking a look at my question, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `? mvfft` (with `inverse = TRUE`)?

`mvfft` does the (inverse) FFT by columns, but you can reshape your data:

- `t` for matrix transpose
- `aperm` for an array extension of `t` (dimension permutation)
- you can reshape your array to a matrix by `dim<-`
  (package arrayhelpers has convenience functions for such conversion of an array into a matrix and back).

Comment: Thank you cbeleites. I'm very much a novice with R, any chance you might be able to explain it to be like im 5 haha. Are you saying for me to change the x matrix before passing it to `mvfft`

Comment: @Resso: `mvfft (x, inverse = TRUE)` behaves like `ifft (x, [], dim = 2)` in Matlab. That is, you need to have the dimension along which the FFT is to take place in the *columns*. Do you have a matrix or an array?

Comment: I had an error when attempting to use `mvfft`: "vector-valued (multivariate) series required". My array is over 2000 elements large unfortunately. I can get the `ifft` to work with `fft(x, inverse=TRUE)/length(x)`, without the `dim` dimension, but I cannot convert the matlab code `ifft(x,z,2)`, where the value of `z` is `3528`

Comment: is there a way to prepare my matrix/array to be multivariate so I may make use of mvfft?

Comment: @Resso you should edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example, with mockup data, so that people can provide a definite answer.

Comment: @baptiste I would it's just that my sample data is ~4000 elements in the array, and I'm trying to compare the results I have in Matlab to what I'm getting in R. If I cut a few lines out of the array and pasted it here, I don't think it would be helpful.

Comment: again, it doesn't have to be your data, or 4000 elements for that matter. Just something minimal and reproducible with the same _structure_; using arbitrary numbers or built-in datasets. You can then compare R and Matlab results on this simple test, and scale it up to your real data.

Comment: @Resso: you'll have to take care of `N = z` by yourself. I'm not exactly familiar with the Matlab code, but if that is the no of output points, you'll have to cut your matrix appropriately before using `mvfft`. baptiste is right. Prepare a small (say 10 x 5) matrix, and compare the Matlab results on that with the R results. That should get you going.